# How can I view all the details in a SQL Server agent job history log entry?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016, error-logging, sql-server-agent

I am trying to view the details of a SQL Server agent job history log entry. What I am seeing is the following:

```
Date        2/1/2021 8:30:01 AM
Log     Job History (Every 10 Minutes Transaction Log Backup.Subplan_1)

Step ID     1
Server      SQL-SERVER
Job Name        Every 10 Minutes Transaction Log Backup.Subplan_1
Step Name       Subplan_1
Duration        00:00:06
Sql Severity    0
Sql Message ID  0
Operator Emailed    
Operator Net sent   
Operator Paged  
Retries Attempted   0

Message
Executed as user: CC\sqlserveragent. ... 14.0.2037.2 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  8:30:01 AM  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:01.39     Source: {4720AEAA-15ED-4DCA-A83D-079899E0FD78}      Executing query "DECLARE @Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.03     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 4% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.03     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 9% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 13% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 18% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 22% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 27% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 31% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 36% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 40% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.04     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 45% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 50% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 54% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 59% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 63% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 68% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 72% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 77% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 81% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 86% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database ...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.
```

I have read multiple posts about limiting the size of the log and removing log files older than X days/weeks etc. but I cannot seem to find anything related to showing or configuring logging to show the complete details of each line item in the log. Here is a more specific example from the log I posted above:

```
Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database (Transaction Log)      Executing query "EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir N'\\FILE-SERVE...".: 86% complete  End Progress  Progress: 2021-02-01 08:30:03.06     Source: Back Up Database ...  The package execution fa...  The step failed.
```

Within that example, you can see the ellipses (...) that are used to abbreviate the log entry. You can also see that the information in the entry is not enough to determine the problem. So...

How do I configure SQL Server or SQL Server Management Studio to log the entire query being executed and the reason for the failure?

Comment: Have you done this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754378/how-can-i-view-full-sql-job-history     https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/95333/get-detailed-output-of-sql-agent-job

Comment: Is this executing an SSIS package?

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you for sharing that post. I am not sure that I would call that intuitive but I appreciate the assistance locating an obscure setting.